# How save t-shirt created in web printing creator bulied with javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having some problem with my current project. I'm making t-shirt creator somethink similar to this:http://www.zazzle.com/cr/design/pt-shirt using javascript with jquery.

Now I have no idea how to save t-shirt project created using this. My only idea, but I don't think it is good, is to send all coordinates of objects to PHP script and then using fpdf create pdf from this. Using similar technique, I mean sending coordinates to php script, I can also make a bitmap file.
But as you can see this is quite complicated and long method.

So do you know any technique to save such a project to PDF and bitmap file?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT:**

I though that the best place for anserws on *nyarlathotep*'s questions would be in here.

> what format are your t-shirt designs in(1), what kind of data do you have there(2)? what have you tried so far(3)? Being that vague, there is no real answer to your question

1. there isn`t anything like t-shirt format I thought that this is obvious - this is simple web page where you can place pictures or text on other pictures.
2. data is just pictures (or more accuret img tags into divs), or text, aldo in divs.
3. for me this is weired question. I've mentioned my idea, but it isn't good because it is very complicated and I supose that there is easier way for that.

Comment: what format are your t-shirt designs in, what kind of data do you have there? what have you tried so far? Being that vague, there is no real answer to your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many tries and tests, only one option seems to work, which is the first option - save all coordinates.

Technically, I am now using predefined in size and position rectangle inside which I am moving around my objects (objects are added dynamically). To move object I am using jQuery methods for objects moving. Also I am using some methods for resizing (jQuery).

After all, everything is send to PHP. Than it is "redrawn" onto PDF using fpdf and this picture (PDF) is presented to a user.

After some code optimization it is the easiest and fastest way which I came up with.

I hope it will help someone at the beginning.

Comment: Hi, I am also looking to make one similar interface. Were you successful?